# Mass in de Broglie Formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, momentum, mass, wavelength

Regarding [de Broglie formula](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/De_Broglie_wavelength)

$$\lambda= h/mv$$

here m is relative mass or rest mass?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363326/380387

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula is $\lambda = h /p$ and $ p = \gamma m v $, where $m$ is the rest mass.